# Fixed Div On Top, Div that Fills Rest of Page on Bottom - CSS

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to get a layout that has **no scrollbars** and has a **fixed header div(height 150px)** and then below that a **div that fills the rest of the page** (will be a google map).

### The problem

The map extend down below the bottom of the view-port and I get a scrollbar.

I am looking for a CSS only solution.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#map
{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#bb3311;
}
#header
{
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#00ffbb;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* do not use universal selector this is just for example */
#container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add overflow hidden where needed.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work in IE 6 (7 or 8 I am not sure, but doubtful)

Comment: If you care about IE 6 check this out: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/  From mentioned article: "In all browsers except for IE5 and IE6

   1. A div is rectangular.
   2. All four corners of a div can be absolutely positioned on a page.
   3. If the location of diagonally opposing corners has been determined the width and height is implied."