# Div height 100% within div

Tags: html, css

I got the followin code, which doesn't do the trick:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="navigation">    
        <ul>      
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>


     <div id="main">
       Content
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the wrap to be 100% height. This works just fine. But as soon as i try the #main div to be 100% heights as well, it doesn't. This div always collapses to the height of content.

```
html{height:100%;}
body{overflow-y:scroll; margin:0px; padding:0px; height:100%;}
#wrap{
    min-height: 100%; /* Mindesthöhe für moderne Browser */
    height:auto !important; /* Important Regel für moderne Browser */ 
    height:100%; /* Mindesthöhe für den IE */ 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#main{
    width: 980px !important;


    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
    height:auto !important;


}
```

Can somebody please help me solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are setting the height of #main to 100% of height:auto, which doesn't exist.

Comment: get completely rid of `height:auto !important`

Comment: Please give us a bit more information about the effect you're trying to achieve. Maybe we can help with an alternate solution. Are you trying to have #main fill the rest of the page below the navigation?

Comment: @showdev i would do it on an alternative way, but the problem is that the navigation with has to be 100%; the content with is only allowed to be 980px.

Comment: @showdev yes, i want the #main element to fill the rest of the page. It shall be centered by #main {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; background:red;}

Comment: Possible solutions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898221/make-div-fill-remainder-of-page-vertically) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453278/fixed-div-on-top-div-that-fills-rest-of-page-on-bottom-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the style for `wrap`. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PrH8S/)

```css
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%; /* Minimum height for modern browsers */
    height:100%; /* Minimum height for IE */ 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Leaving away the height:auto !important; did the trick ;)

Comment: This does not work if the #main content is longer than the page. It gets truncated because the height is limited to 100%. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/PrH8S/2/).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it doesn't seem that the #main div necessarily needs to expand to 100%. What needs to expand is the red background.

I suggest using a "faux background". Using `position:fixed`, you can add a red background that will not scroll with the page. The rest of the content can scroll over it. Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/izasil/1/).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div#background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div#background div#color {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 980px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div#nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

div#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="color"></div>
</div>

<div id="nav">NAVIGATION<br />even two lines<br /> or more</div>

<div id="main">
  <p>CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain your votes. It helps to improve answers.